# Fairly rank values

Tags: code-golf, sorting

## Task

Given an input list of integers **x<sub>1</sub>…x<sub>n</sub>**, compute a list of ranks **r<sub>1</sub>…r<sub>n</sub>** (a permutation of **{1…n}**) so that **x<sub>r<sub>1</sub></sub> ≤ x<sub>r<sub>2</sub></sub> ≤ … ≤ x<sub>r<sub>n</sub></sub>**. Then, for each **x<sub>i</sub>**, replace its rank by the arithmetic mean of the ranks of all values in **x** that are equal to **x<sub>i</sub>**. (That is, whenever there is a tie between equal values in **x**, fairly redistribute the ranks among all of them.) Output the modified list of ranks **r’<sub>1</sub>…r’<sub>n</sub>**.

<sup>(For statistics geeks: such a ranking of observations is used in the [Mann–Whitney *U* test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Calculations) (method two, step 1.))</sup>

## Example

Given an input list **[3, -6, 3, 3, 14, 3]**, the first list of ranks would be **[2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5]**, which would sort the list into **[-6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 14]**. Then, the ranks for all **3**s in the input list are evened out into **(2 + 3 + 4 + 5) ÷ 4 = 3.5**. The final output is **[3.5, 1, 3.5, 3.5, 6, 3.5]**.

## Test cases

```
[4, 1, 4] -> [2.5, 1.0, 2.5]
[5, 14, 14, 14, 14, 5, 14] -> [1.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.5, 5.0]
[9, 9, -5, -5, 13, -5, 13, 9, 9, 13] -> [5.5, 5.5, 2.0, 2.0, 9.0, 2.0, 9.0, 5.5, 5.5, 9.0]
[13, 16, 2, -5, -5, -5, 13, 16, -5, -5] -> [7.5, 9.5, 6.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.5, 9.5, 3.0, 3.0]
```

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Somewhat](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fairly#Adverb) [disgusting](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rank#Adjective) [values](//example.com/just/linking/somewhere/so/the/comment/looks/consistent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ð_'Ṡ‘S‘H
```

*Saved 2 bytes by using the `cmp` trick from [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81100).*

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w7BfJ-G5oOKAmFPigJhI&input=&args=WzMsIC02LCAzLCAzLCAxNCwgM10) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w7BfJ-G5oOKAmFPigJhICsOH4oKsRw&input=&args=WzQsIDEsIDRdLCBbNSwgMTQsIDE0LCAxNCwgMTQsIDUsIDE0XSwgWzksIDksIC01LCAtNSwgMTMsIC01LCAxMywgOSwgOSwgMTNdLCBbMTMsIDE2LCAyLCAtNSwgLTUsIC01LCAxMywgMTYsIC01LCAtNV0).

#### How it works

```
ð_'Ṡ‘S‘H  Main link. Left argument: A (list of values)

ð         Make the chain dyadic, setting the right argument to A.
 _'       Spawned subtraction; compute the matrix of differences.
   Ṡ      Apply the sign function to each difference.
    ‘     Increment.
     S    Sum across columns.
      ‘   Increment.
       H  Halve.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 12

```
m+l<#dQ.OS/Q
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2Bl%3C%23dQ.OS%2FQ&input=%5B5%2C+14%2C+14%2C+14%2C+14%2C+5%2C+14%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B4%2C+1%2C+4%5D%0A%5B5%2C+14%2C+14%2C+14%2C+14%2C+5%2C+14%5D%0A%5B9%2C+9%2C+-5%2C+-5%2C+13%2C+-5%2C+13%2C+9%2C+9%2C+13%5D%0A%5B13%2C+16%2C+2%2C+-5%2C+-5%2C+-5%2C+13%2C+16%2C+-5%2C+-5%5D&debug=0)

For each value this computes the arithmetic mean of `[1..frequency]` and adds the count of values less than the current one.

This works because for each value we would compute:

```
(1 / frequency) * sum (i = 1..frequency) i + count_less
```

which we can simplify to:

```
(1 / frequency) * [ frequency * (frequency + 1) / 2 + count_less * frequency ]
```

and again to:

```
(frequency + 1) / 2 + count_less
```

However, in Pyth it was golfier to compute the first summand by using the mean builtin, rather than this other formula.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 51 bytes

```python
lambda l:[-~sum(1+cmp(y,x)for x in l)/2.for y in l]
```

For each element `y`, the `cmp` expression gives 2 points for each smaller `x` and 1 point for each equal `x`. This sum is rescaled into the right range by adding 1 and halving. The `2.` is needed to avoid integer division.

**Python 3, 52 bytes**

Python 3 lacks `cmp`, requiring a Boolean expression (+2 bytes), but it has float division (-1 byte).

```python
lambda l:[-~sum((y>x)+(y>=x)for x in l)/2for y in l]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
7#utG&S&S2XQw)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NyN1dEcmUyZTMlhRdyk&input=WzEzLCAxNiwgMiwgLTUsIC01LCAtNSwgMTMsIDE2LCAtNSwgLTVd) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YFhJCjcjdXRJJlMmUzJYUXcpCiFEVAo&input=WzMsIC02LCAzLCAzLCAxNCwgM10KWzQsIDEsIDRdCls1LCAxNCwgMTQsIDE0LCAxNCwgNSwgMTRdCls5LCA5LCAtNSwgLTUsIDEzLCAtNSwgMTMsIDksIDksIDEzXQpbMTMsIDE2LCAyLCAtNSwgLTUsIC01LCAxMywgMTYsIC01LCAtNV0) (slightly modified version of the code; each result is on a different line).

```
      % Implicit input. Example: [5 14 14 14 14 5 14]
7#u   % Replace each value by a unique, integer label. Example: [1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 1; 2]
t     % Duplicate
G&S   % Push input again. Sort and get indices of the sorting. Example: [1 6 2 3 4 5 7]
&S    % Sort and get the indices, again. This gives the ranks. Example: [1 3 4 5 6 2 7]
2XQ   % Compute mean of ranks for equal values of the integer label. Example: [1.5; 5]
w     % Swap top two elements in stack
)     % Index the means with the integer labels. Example: [1.5; 5; 5; 5; 5; 1.5; 5]
      % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

Code:

```
v¹y‹O¹yQO>;+ˆ
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dsK5eeKAuU_CuXlRTz47K8uG&input=WzEzLCAxNiwgMiwgLTUsIC01LCAtNSwgMTMsIDE2LCAtNSwgLTVd).

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>17</s> 12 bytes

Takes the input from STDIN outputs to STDOUT.  If the output is flexible then we can ditch the `cat()`.

```
rank(scan())
```

Fairly simple, uses the builtin rank that defaults to average for a tie breaker.

In use:

```
> rank(scan())
1: 5 14 14 14 14 5 14
8: 
Read 7 items
[1] 1.5 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 1.5 5.0
> rank(scan())
1: 3 -6 3 3 14 3
7: 
Read 6 items
[1] 3.5 1.0 3.5 3.5 6.0 3.5
>
```

Comment: You may drop the `cat()`, if it’s up to me. I don’t know what the community consensus is, though.

Comment: @Lynn Thanks I will.  I can always put it back.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 18 bytes

```
1-:@+1+/"1@:+*@-/~
```

Based on Dennis' [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81089) using xnor's [method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81100).

Using a straight-forward approach requires **24 bytes** for me.

```
(i.~~.){](+/%#)/.1+/:@/:
```

### Usage

```
   f =: 1-:@+1+/"1@:+*@-/~
   f 3 _6 3 3 14 3
3.5 1 3.5 3.5 6 3.5
   f 4 1 4
2.5 1 2.5
   f 5 14 14 14 14 5 14
1.5 5 5 5 5 1.5 5
   f 9 9 _5 _5 13 _5 13 9 9 13
5.5 5.5 2 2 9 2 9 5.5 5.5 9
   f 13 16 2 _5 _5 _5 13 16 _5 _5
7.5 9.5 6 3 3 3 7.5 9.5 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 18 bytes

```
;╗`╝╜"╛-su"£MΣu½`M
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KVl2DilZ3ilZwi4pWbLXN1IsKjTc6jdcK9YE0&input=WzMsIC02LCAzLCAzLCAxNCwgM10)

This is essentially a port of [xnor's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81100/45941).

Explanation:

```
;╗`╝╜"╛-su"£MΣu½`M
;╗                  push a copy of input to reg0
  `             `M  for x in input:
   ╝                  push x to reg1
    ╜                 push input from reg0
     "    "£M         for y in input:
      ╛                 push x from reg0
       -s               cmp(y,x) (sgn(y-x))
         u              add 1
             Σu½      sum, add 1, half
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 30 bytes

```
!x=-~sum((x.>x')+(x.>=x'),2)/2
```

This uses an approach from [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81100). Julia has `cmp`, but it doesn't vectorize.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IXg9LX5zdW0oKHguPngnKSsoeC4-PXgnKSwyKS8yCgpmb3IgeCBpbiAoWzQsIDEsIDRdLCBbNSwgMTQsIDE0LCAxNCwgMTQsIDUsIDE0XSwgWzksIDksIC01LCAtNSwgMTMsIC01LCAxMywgOSwgOSwgMTNdLCBbMTMsIDE2LCAyLCAtNSwgLTUsIC01LCAxMywgMTYsIC01LCAtNV0pCiAgICBkaXNwbGF5KCF4KQogICAgcHJpbnRsbigpCmVuZA&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 17 chars

```
(y+.×⍋X)÷+/y←∘.=⍨X
```

Assuming the list is stored in `X`.

### Explanation:

Note that APL evaluates expressions from right to left. Then:

- `∘.=⍨X` = `X∘.=X` where `∘.=` is the outer product using `=` as dyadic function. (Where you normally would multiply. So the mathematical outer product may be written as `∘.×`.)
- The resulting matrix is stored in `y` and `y` is directly folded using `+` to give a vector of the number of equal objects for each rank (lets call it `z←+/y`).
- `⍋X` returns the ranks of `X`
- `y+.×⍋X` gives the inner product of our matrix y with this vector.
- The result is divided (component wise) by `z`.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```
a=>a.map(n=>a.reduce((r,m)=>r+(n>m)+(n>=m),1)/2)
```

Edit: Saved 1 byte by reformulating the expression so it now looks like @xnor's Python 3 answer.